# WPF Prism 5.0 Interaction popup - how to make it not to display in TaskBar?

Tags: wpf, prism

If you have Prism 5.0 - it has a sample solution
Quickstarts\Interactivity\InteractivityQuickstart

it shows how to use popup UserControls that have their views defined
InteractivityQuickstart\Views\InteractionRequestView.xaml:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CustomPopupViewRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
<!-- This PopupWindowAction has a custom view defined. When this action is executed the view will be shown inside a new window -->
<!-- Take into account that the view is created only once and will be reused each time the action is executed -->
    <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <views:CustomPopupView />
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

It all works fine, except that this popup shows its own taskbar button.
And it can only be a UserControl, not a Window - can't set ShowInTaskBar="False".

Anyone can help - how to make it not to display its own taskbar button?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are some limitation in Prism popupwindow, so you cannot control it.
Instead of that you can try using

http://blogs.southworks.net/dcherubini/2012/05/24/popupwindowaction-using-custom-views-instead-of-windows-in-wpf-and-prism/

Great thing about this solution is - that you can use custom pop-ups and not only Notification or Confirmation pop-ups.

Also - You can pass information back to the class the invoked the 'InteractionRequest'.

Answer (score 3):

UserControl have not a property ShowInTaskBar.
Just set the property **ShowInTaskBar** of the **window** to **False** it should works, like this :

```html
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CustomPopupViewRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
<!-- This PopupWindowAction has a custom view defined. When this action is executed the view will be shown inside a new window -->
<!-- Take into account that the view is created only once and will be reused each time the action is executed -->
    <prism:PopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True">
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>
          <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="ShowInTaskbar" Value="False"/>
          </Style>
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>

        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <views:CustomPopupView />
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>

    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

best regards.

Comment: You get a XAML parse error on <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowStyle>

Comment: @GarethOates The code works fine, prism has some limitation about this, but in the next version i think that there is some news in this issue, https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/310#issuecomment-158736457

Comment: We must be running different versions of Prism. I'm currently developing in Prism 5.0.0 and when I attempt to overwrite the window style, I get an InvalidParseException.

Comment: Looking at the source code, this wasn't added until version 6.0.1. So yes, the code does work fine if you're running Prism 6 and beyond, but the OP is asking specifically about Prism 5.

Here's the commit that added the functionality.

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/commit/a4446ddcf00c9a3f4dac2f49a29890231f46abd5